# How to add new DLL locations to WebAPI's controller discovery?

Tags: asp.net-web-api

ASP.NET WebAPI has a much appreciated ability to discover ApiController classes in external DLLs even if those DLLs are not referenced. For example, I may have MyWebApiProject that has a set of ApiControllers. I could then create a completely separate project called MyApiProjectPlugin that contains ApiController classes also. I have been able to add the MyApiProjectPlugin.dll file to the bin folder with the first MyApiProject.dll and the original project will discover all the controllers in the plugin project. I really like that ability.

However, What I would like to do is be able to add the plugin project to a sub directory inside of the bin folder. Something like bin/plugins. When I tried this, the original MyApiProject was unable to discover the plugin's controllers.

Is there a simple way to get WebAPI to look for ApiController classes in the bin's subdirectories? If I can avoid rewriting a controller factory from scratch I would like to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can write an assembly resolver.

```cs
public class PluginsResolver : DefaultAssembliesResolver
{
    public override ICollection<Assembly> GetAssemblies()
    {
        List<Assembly> assemblies = new List<Assembly>(base.GetAssemblies());
    
        assemblies.Add(Assembly.LoadFrom(@"<Path>\MyApiProjectPlugin.dll"));
    
        return assemblies;
    }
}
```

In the Register method in WebApiConfig, register the resolver.

```cs
config.Services.Replace(typeof(IAssembliesResolver), new PluginsResolver());
```