# ASP.NET Core MVC main project can't reach Controllers in separate assembly

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017

I want to use a separate project to store the Controllers for my test app. Due to how `ASP.NET Core` is working, you need to  call `services.AddMvc().AddApplicationPart` with the assembly you want to add.

I use **Visual Studio 2017** (so no more `project.json` there)

The problem is I can't reach the assembly I want to include!

I added reference there in my project:

[image]

Also, I decided to use polyfill for AppDomian like so (to reach assembly I need):

```
 public class AppDomain
    {
        public static AppDomain CurrentDomain { get; private set; }

        static AppDomain()
        {
            CurrentDomain = new AppDomain();
        }

        public Assembly[] GetAssemblies()
        {
            var assemblies = new List<Assembly>();
            var dependencies = DependencyContext.Default.RuntimeLibraries;
            foreach (var library in dependencies)
            {
                if (IsCandidateCompilationLibrary(library))
                {
                    var assembly = Assembly.Load(new AssemblyName(library.Name));
                    assemblies.Add(assembly);
                }
            }
            return assemblies.ToArray();
        }

        private static bool IsCandidateCompilationLibrary(RuntimeLibrary compilationLibrary)
        {
            return compilationLibrary.Name == ("TrainDiary")
                || compilationLibrary.Dependencies.Any(d => d.Name.StartsWith("TrainDiary"));
        }
    }
```

But when I used it there wasonly one assembly in the list (only linked to this project itself, not one with Controllers).

Here is my `Startup.cs`:

```
public class Startup
    {

        public IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; }
        public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
                .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
                .AddEnvironmentVariables();

            Configuration = builder.Build();
        }
        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        // For more information on how to configure your application, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            var assemblies = GetAssemblies(); // I tought I will find there Assmbly I need but no

            services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
            services.AddReact();
            services.AddMvc();
            services.AddLogging();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            loggerFactory.AddConsole();

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseReact(config =>
            {
            });

            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();
        }

        public List<Assembly> GetAssemblies()
        {
            Assembly[] assemblies = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies();
            List<Assembly> currentAssemblies = new List<Assembly>();

            foreach (Assembly assembly in assemblies)
            {
                if (assembly.GetName().Name.Contains("TrainDiary"))
                {
                    currentAssemblies.Add(assembly);
                }
            }

            return currentAssemblies;
        }

    }
```

How can I get my project to also lookup controllers in the other project? Why couldn't it see it?

**UPD**

Tried to make directly like in this [exapmle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37725934/asp-net-core-mvc-controllers-in-separate-assembly) here.

So my code started looks like that:

```
var controllersAssembly = Assembly.Load(new AssemblyName("TrainDiary.Controllers")); 
services.AddMvc()
        .AddApplicationPart(controllersAssembly)
        .AddControllersAsServices();
```

And it succeed to get the assembly:

[image]

But when I try to call Controller function - it fails!

Controller code:

```
[Route("Login")]
    public class LoginController: Controller
    {
        [Route("Login/Test")]
        public void Test(string name, string password)
        {
            string username = name;
            string pass = password;
        }
    }
```

Requests:

[image]

**UPD2**:

For some reason remove `Routes` helped:

```
public class LoginController: Controller
    {
        public void Test(string name, string password)
        {
            string username = name;
            string pass = password;
        }
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So, if sum this up:

1) You need to `Add Reference` to your separate project with
    controllers.

2) Configure services (part):

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
  var controllersAssembly = Assembly.Load(newAssemblyName("SomeProject.MeetTheControllers"));

  services.AddMvc().AddApplicationPart(controllersAssembly).AddControllersAsServices();
}
```

3) My configure looks like that (pay attention to `UseMvcWithDefaultRoute`):

```
   // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            loggerFactory.AddConsole();

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseReact(config =>
            {
            });

            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();
        }
```

So in my case of controller like this you don't need to put `Routes` attribute here, just call it by `Some/Test` url

```
namespace SomeProject.MeetTheControllers.Test
{
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

    public class SomeController: Controller
    {
        public void Test(string name, string notname)
        {
            string username = name;
            string nan = notname;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It’s worth pointing out that this type of work can easily be farmed out to an extension method in the library containing the controllers (e.g., by extending `IMvcBuilder`), potentially alongside other configuration defaults (e.g., registering services, configuring `IViewLocationExpander`s, &c.). In a real-world library where `Controller` instances are housed in a separate assembly, this might be useful, and help eliminate the need for extra configuration.

Comment: It doesn't work for me because it cannot find the view from the controller.