# Using reflection with class library exported as nuget asp.net core

Tags: reflection, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-1.1

I created a class library in .net core and and hosted  class library on my local nuget server.Class library contains controllers and some other classes to be used by reflection.

I consumed this class library in my asp.net core  MVC project.By installing it as nuget refrence. Now my MVC project builds well but at runtime I am not able to find my contoller or other classes defined in class library.

**weird  behavior**  when I copy dll of my class library to my MVC projects bin\Debug\netcoreapp1.1 directory, reflection starts working.

this is happening when i run my application in debug mode on IIS Express and I am using .net core 1.1 on Visual studio 2015

**Question**: Is there a way to extract nuget packages in to bin\Debug\netcoreapp1.1 on build.
**Question**: Do I need to added some configuration so that Reflection look for dll in respective nuget package location.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this answer, it might cover what you are looking for.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/38252635/138029

**UPDATE:**
You could try adding a `NuGet.config` file to your project root.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
 <packageSources>
   <add key="AspNetVNext" value="https://www.myget.org/F/aspnetcidev/api/v3/index.json" />
   <add key="NuGet" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" protocolVersion="3" />
   <add key="Local" value="[PATH_TO_YOUR_NUGET_PACKAGES]" />
  </packageSources>
</configuration>
```

As an aside, if the directory is local to the project root you can commit those local packages to the Source Control. This allows build tools like Visual Studio Team Services to reference them automatically when they build.

Comment: My case is bit different that above case . Dll I reference are never copied to  bin\Debug\netcoreapp1.1 ,they are placed in C:\Users\myaccountname\.nuget\packages. As dll are never copied to  bin\Debug\netcoreapp1.1 reflection could not locate them.

Comment: Do you have a nuget.config that references that package folder?

Comment: there is project.json in asp.netcore no nuget.config file