# Controller does not find the view when the startup is in another project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

To write the integration tests more easily, I've put the controllers in another project than the host (the one with the startup). This project has the following files:

```
|
|-- Controllers
|   +-- HomeController.cs
|
+-- Views
    +-- Home
        +-- Index.cshtml
```

My startup can find the controller thanks to [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38252635/4498831):

```
services.AddMvc().AddApplicationPart(typeof(HomeController).Assembly);
```

However, I didn't find any way to set the path of the views. It seems to be relative to the startup place, and not the controller: when I run the application, I get that error:

```
InvalidOperationException: The view 'Index' was not found. The following locations were searched:
/Views/Home/Index.cshtml
/Views/Shared/Index.cshtml
/Pages/Shared/Index.cshtml
```

How to specify that the views are in the same folder that the controllers?

Comment: I've tried this solution, and it did not work: https://www.jackhiston.com/2017/8/15/sharing-controllers-and-views-in-aspnet-core/

Comment: I'm not that familiar with Asp.Net Core, but in .Net Framework MVC, you would implement a custom `IViewEngine`.

Comment: @FrenchBoiethios 1. I tried the [solution](https://www.jackhiston.com/2017/8/15/sharing-controllers-and-views-in-aspnet-core/) you mentioned above, it works fine for me. Did you add the `<EmbeddedResource ...>` within the library? 2. Apart from that solution, a much easier way is to change your controllers & views project to be **[Razor component Library, RCL]**, and then simply add a reference to the RCL, in this case, there's no need to `AddApplicationPart()` as well as `Configure<RazorViewEngineOptions>`

Comment: @itminus 1. I'm stupid, I did add the `<EmbeddedResource>` tag in the host project. It works when I put it inside the library project 2. This solution is indeed the best one. Since you solved my issue, can you write an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. I tried the solution you mentioned above, it works fine for me. Did you add the `<EmbeddedResource ...>` within the library?
2. Apart from that solution, a much easier way is to change your controllers & views project to be a **[Razor component Library, RCL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/class-libraries?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio)**:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc" Version="2.2.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

and then simply add a reference to the `RCL`, in this case, there's no need to `AddApplicationPart()` as well as `.Configure<RazorViewEngineOptions>()`

Comment: The reference to `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc` was marked as private in my csproj, so I had to remove the `PrivateAssets="All"` for this solution to work.

Comment: @FrenchBoiethios I update the demo `*.csproj` of RCL  for reference :)